# prevent divide by zero when both values are obtained from a calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to complete the following:

(value_a + value_b)/(value_c + value_d)

Usually I have avoided a divide by zero error with something like this:

```
CASE WHEN value_a + value_b = 0
     THEN 0
     ELSE (value_a + value_b)/(value_c + value_d)
END
```

For some reason in this isn't working, which makes me wonder if in the past one of my result sets have never included zero's.

Any pointers on this would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're checking the *numerator*, not the *denominator*:

```
CASE WHEN value_c + value_d = 0
     THEN 0
     ELSE (value_a + value_b)/(value_c + value_d)
END
```

Anothere way is to use `NULLIF` and `COALESCE`:

```
COALESCE((value_a + value_b)/NULLIF((value_c + value_d),0)
  ,0)
```